# Accessibility and complex HTML forms: How to use headings between form controls?

Tags: html, forms, accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

A client needs to create quite a complex form. We use `<fieldset>`/`<legend>` to group certain elements together. But it's not enough - even if we nest them.

Think about the following:

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Your personal details</legend>

    <label>First name: <input name="first_name"></label>
    <label>Last name:  <input name="last_name"></label>

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Gender</legend>

      <label>Male:   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"></label>
      <label>Female: <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"></label>
      <label>Other:  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"></label>
    </fieldset>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Imagine this is only a small part of a bigger form. For example, we could have a "postal address" and a "billing address". Would we need to "indent" the whole thing once more using `<fieldset>`/`<legend>`s?

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Postal address</legend>

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Your personal details</legend>
      ...

      <fieldset>
        <legend>Gender</legend>
        ...
      </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Billing address</legend>

    ...
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Or should we rather use headings?

```html
<form>
  <h2>Postal address</h2>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Your personal details</legend>
    ...

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Gender</legend>
      ...
    </fieldset>
  </fieldset>

  <h2>Billing address</h2>
  ...
</form>
```

While it's probably valid to nest `<fieldset>`/`<legend>`s, I would not over-do it. Party because JAWS will announce the `<legend>` for each contained input element (in contrast to NVDA that will only announce it once, when reaching the first contained input element).

On the other hand, headings will not be announced at all by desktop screen readers when jumping between form elements using `Tab`/`Shift-Tab`. So its information will easily be missed.

What do you think about that, dear screen reader experts? Should we use `aria-describedby` to attach the headings to the subsequent `<fieldset>`? What if there's more than one `<fieldset>` below that heading?

I feel there's no perfect solution here. Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly valid to nest fieldset+legend, but as you ahve said, some screen readers will repeat it for each of the elements under that legend.
It makes a lot of totally useless redundency.

There is certainly no perfect solution, and no normative solution on this either, but I would go for an hybrid structure.
Use legend only for the deepest level, where elements are really close together such as male/female, yes/no, etc. (i.e. groups of radio buttons), and headings for all the rest and intermediate levels. For example:

```
<h2>Personal information</h2>
<fieldset>
<legend>Gender</legend>
...
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend>Marital status</legend>
...
</legend>
</fieldset>
<h2>Billing address</h2>
...
<h2>Delivery address</h2>
...
```

Headings have a great bonus advantage, there are shortcuts keys to jump directly to them. It's especially useful when you want to modify only one or two particular fields in the whole form. You can't do this with legend.

IF you are afraid that the screen reader user miss "Personal information", "Billing address" and "Delivery address", you may use aria-labelledby refering two IDs:

```
<h2 id="billingAddressHeading">Billing address</h2>
<p><label id="streetLabel" for=street">Street: </label>
<input type="text" aria-labelledby="streetLabel billingAddressHeading"/>
</p>
```

If you use two IDs like that only on the first field of the group, you make sure that the screen reader won't uselessly read the group label for each of the fields.

Be careful to not forget to reference the label itself in aria-labelledby, because it replaces completely the `<label>`.

Note that, technically, you are also allowed to use fieldsets without legen.

```
<h2 id="billingAddressHeading">Billing address</h2>
<p><label id="streetLabel" for=street">Street: </label>
<input type="text" aria-labelledby="streetLabel billingAddressHeading"/>
</p>
```

As a final note, if you find the form getting too complex, it's maybe the time to think about splitting it into several smaller pages.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @QuentinC! You confirm what I know and feel about the topic. Would you say that desktop screen reader users should be aware of the fact that they miss certain non-focusable parts inside a form, if they lazily/conveniently stick to just hitting `Tab` key, instead of switching back to browse mode? Back in the days, I learned that we should help screen reader users by attaching non-focusable parts using `aria-describedby` and such. But I feel that you cannot force web designers to attach headings to input fields, just because screen reader users are "lazy". What do you think?

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim First of, I would disagree heartily that screen reader users are "lazy".  SR users are some of the hardest working web surfers because they have to deal with so many poorly written pages that they have to hunt for information exhaustively.  The easier you make it for them, the better.  As a sighted user, you can see all the associated information based on the screen layout.  Why shouldn't a SR user have that benefit too?

Comment: I agree with @quentinc's latter suggestion to use `aria-labelledby` to associate the heading with the input field.  You might consider `aria-describedby` if you think the heading is more "parenthetical" and should be announced **after** the accessible name rather than as *part* of the accessible name, as long as you know SR users can turn off descriptions so they might not hear it announced.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, @slugolicious. I wonder whether from a WCAG standpoint of view we are **required** to connect non-focusable info to form fields using the described methods. (Even using multiple `<label>` elements would be a valid option, right?) Or is it to just make life a little bit easier for those using strictly `Tab` to navigate forms? And I'm not talking about the one "main" `<label>` that needs to be connected to each and every form input, but about additional info like `<p>` (i.e. with terms and conditions) or `<h#>` elements (for structuring).

Comment: I can't speak for all SR users, but if you look at [WebAim survey](https://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey9/) on the "finding information" question, headings is way ahead, and Ctrl+F and reading through with =arrow keys) are also ahead from navigating through links (with tab).
Therefore, there aren't that many SR users who use only tab.
I wouldn't say that we are lazy. IN the opposite, maybe we are even more persevering than average, since we always have to fight against everything to be heard, on the net as well as in real life.

Comment: I think that sooner or later, we become aware that we miss information if we only use tab.
By the way, personally I feel lost  in too well made apps where you can navigate with tab, but not by headings or simply with arrow keys.
Many people associate screen reader with using tab exclusively, and nothing is more wrong than that.

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim "I wonder whether from a WCAG standpoint of view we are **required** to connect non-focusable info to form fields".  Perfectly valid question. WCAG can be very subjective. It often doesn't explicitly say certain things are required. In this case 1.3.1 is the guideline. It says if a "relationship is conveyed through presentation" then it must be programmatically associated too (eg with `aria-labelledby`). Using real headings (`<h2>`) or nested legends **does** programmatically associate so from a pure **required** standpoint, no you don't need **additional** `aria-labelledby`.

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim But any accessibility professional will tell you that accessibility is more than about conforming to guidelines. It's about the user experience, which is exactly what your question was about, so kudos to you for thinking about that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your extensive additions. I totally agree that screen reader users are not lazy by default, and that we should strive to make the experience for assistive devices as smooth as possible. But sometimes we have to accept compromises, and in the current project I am required to create a blueprint for dozens of other projects, where developers are potentially not that accessibility-aware, and as such we try to give them a rock solid but "manageable" foundation.

Answer (score 0):

Some good practices are described here: https://medium.com/@baryshev.nb/how-to-build-an-accessible-form-with-html5-a98fe833c0e9

They are pretty basic but might be useful and there are code examples.

Comment: The link doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm.. weird. I just checked it and it worked fine